# Cursor(?) in SQL: Iterate through table in WHERE-Statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, cursor

Currently I have a problem with SQL. I am working with SQL Server 2014.

Some background: I uploaded lots of weather data from `.csv` files into a table named `dbo.import`. Because the data is not adjusted/corrected so I chose mostly "text" as data type.

I have many duplicate rows identified and I wrote them in a new table named `dbo.duplikate`

```
INSERT INTO dbo.duplikate 
    SELECT 
       airportCode, CAST(DateUTC AS VARCHAR(25)), Count(*) 
   FROM 
       dbo.import
   GROUP BY 
       airportCode, CAST(DateUTC AS VARCHAR(25))
   HAVING 
       Count(*) > 1
```

(Maybe there is a way available how I can write all rows in the new table through a similar statement so I don't need a cursor(?)?)

Now I try to write all duplicates, with all rows (in total 16), in a new table.

My idea was iterate through my table `dbo.duplikate` row for row and compare this in my `WHERE` clause.

Something like this (pseudo-code):

```
INSERT INTO dbo.newTable
   SELECT * 
   FROM dbo.import
   WHERE dbo.import.DateUTC LIKE dbo.duplikate.DateUTC[i] 
     AND dbo.import.airportCode LIKE dbo.duplikate.airportCode[i]
```

Through google I find cursors. But I am not sure if this is the right way. Every try failed because I don't know how to assign the rows to my WHERE clause ...

Regards, 
Julian

Comment: To be sure, your final objective is to delete all duplicates from the `dbo.import` table?

Comment: Never use a cursor if you are not aan experienced dba.

Comment: Yes and no. I would say merge all duplicates. They are identical with my DateUTC and airportCode but different in some of the other values (different values or NULL-values, etc). There I want to make mean values, ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing in your question that makes me believe you need a cursor.  Cursors can be very useful, but performance is almost always better when you perform actions on sets of data rather than looping.

In SQL Server you can use a `ROW_NUMBER()` or a windowed `COUNT()` to identify duplicates without losing the detail as you do in your query:

```
;with cte AS (SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY airportCode, CAST(DateUTC AS VARCHAR(25)) ORDER BY airportCode) RN
                      ,COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY airportCode, CAST(DateUTC AS VARCHAR(25))) Dup_CT
              FROM dbo.import)
SELECT *
FROM cte
```

From there you can add in `WHERE` criteria to suit your needs, for example if you just want to put all records that have a duplicate into a new table you'd use `WHERE Dup_CT > 1`. You can also `DELETE` from the cte if you want to remove duplicate records:

```
;with cte AS (SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY airportCode, CAST(DateUTC AS VARCHAR(25)) ORDER BY airportCode) RN
                      ,COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY airportCode, CAST(DateUTC AS VARCHAR(25))) Dup_CT
              FROM dbo.import)
DELETE FROM cte
WHERE RN > 1
```

You can adjust the `ORDER BY` clause in the `ROW_NUMBER()` function to specify which record you'll keep if performing the above `DELETE`.

Comment: Wow thanks. You are right, I didn't need cursors. Your solution does what I wanted to do (in a much easier way :-D). Thank you :-)